# Issue with Storing JWT in Cookies

Tags: .net, reactjs, jwt

I have been trying to store the JWT I am getting from my OAuth2 server as a cookie in my React application and setting **HttpOnly** flag to true.

I am running a .NET Core backend and I am facing issues with reading the stored cookie on the server side. No matter what, I am always getting only 3 cookies which seem to be the standard ones using Request.Cookies.

2 of them start with **ga** and another one is a **CookieConsent** one. So I am not getting my custom cookies at all.

I have tried both **axios** and **fetch** with the same result.

Comment: Are they in `Request.Cookies`?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. I meant “Request.Cookies”.

Comment: I also used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost but it didn't work. Using 127.0.0.1 caused the 3 standard cookies to disappear too.

Comment: Yes, the "domain" must be the same as those of the cookies. Can you show some code on how you store them? Maybe also a little bit about your setup - is your API in the same domain as your website?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I finally figured out how to fix the issue thanks to [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2416958/stefan) for his comment.

What I did was to move my React app into my .NET project and use .NET's SPA extension to host it.

The issue was happening because of SameSite check with Cookies and although I was setting that value to .Lax/.None I still wasn't able to access my cookies.

Now because I am using a same domain for both my frontend and the API, I am able to read HttpOnly cookies correctly.